# Test class for a pagereference method

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller-extension

I am trying to test a logic in my extension. I have three boolean variable(I am setting them as false in constructor). In my method displayButton() , if all three boolean value are true then I set a specific boolean value named casestatus as false else I set it as true:

```
public Boolean casestatus {get;set;}
public transient Boolean checkfirstname{get;set;}
public transient Boolean checkLastName{get;set;}
public transient Boolean checkSSN{get;set;}
private Contact cnt;
public CreateNewCase.CreateNewCase(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 

{
  casestatus = true;
  checkfirstname = false;
  checkLastName = false;
  checkSSN = false;
 this.cnt = (Contact) stdController.getRecord();
 }
public PageReference displayButton() {
  if (checkfirstname && checkLastName && checkSSN) {
   casestatus = false;
  } else {
   casestatus = true;
  }
  return null;
 }
```

I would like to write a test method for the above method, I started of like this but I am wondering how I will test the logic in the method which return pagereference value as null:

```
@isTest
public class TestCreateNewCase {

    public Boolean checkfirstname=false;
    public Boolean checkLastName=false;
    public Boolean checkSSN=false;
    public Boolean casestatus=false;


public ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

@isTest
static void testdisplayButton(){


CreateNewCase caseobject=new CreateNewCase(stdController);
PageReference resPg = caseobject.displayButton();
System.assertEquals(null, resPg, 'no redirect occurs');

}


}
```

Comment: what's the name of the class being tested? You'll need that to construct it and set its properties

Comment: CreateNewCase is the name of the class. Can show me by example of what you meant? It would be easy for me to grasp if I see how the test looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The testmethod looks like

```
@isTest
private static void testDisplayButton() {
    CreateNewCase ctlr = new CreateNewCase(new ApexPages.StandardController (new Contact());
    ctlr.checkFirstName = false;  // simulate user input from the page
    ctlr.checkLastName = false;
    ctlr.checkSSN = false;

    PageReference resPg = ctlr.displayButton();
    System.assertEquals(null, resPg, 'no redirect occurs');
    System.assertEquals(true, ctlr.caseStatus, 'any input false, status is true');

    ctlr.checkFirstName = true;  // simulate user input from the page
    ctlr.checkLastName = true;
    ctlr.checkSSN = true;

    resPg = ctlr.displayButton();
    System.assertEquals(null, resPg, 'no redirect occurs');
    System.assertEquals(false, ctlr.caseStatus, 'all inputs true, status is false');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it. Actually I have a constructor in my CreateCase class. I need to invoke that in my test class. From what you answered I came up with my test class( Pls see the edited question). However when I run the test class it fails saying - System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object. Stack trace show the error in CreateCase at line where I have -  this.cnt = (Contact) stdController.getRecord();

Comment: @Rdvsm - updated

Comment: Wonderful ! Thanks for getting me started on this!